# extracting multiple data from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display data in table from mysql using php from multiple tables.
i want to display data from different tables of database, and my counting counter is date.

```
$rowac = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryac);
$rowdd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querydd);
$rowbk = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querydk);
$rowdn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querydn);
$rowdis = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querydis);
$rowfar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryfar);
$rowgali = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querygali);
$rowgaz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querygaz);
$rowmay = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querymay);
$rowpes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querypes);
$rowtaj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytaj);
$recordsPerPage = 30;
$start_from= 1;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM date ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $start_from, $recordsPerPage";  

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$row['date'].'</span></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowac['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowdd['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowbk['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowdn['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowdis['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowfar['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowgali['point'] .'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowgaz['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowmay['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowpes['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '<td style="background:#ffffff;"><strong class="fon">'.$rowtaj['point'].'</strong></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        };
        echo "</tr>";
```

what i am doing wrong???

Comment: You are doing wrong by not posting the entire code. How could we help just with this?

Comment: `echo "<tr>"` should at the beginning of the loop body. `echo "</tr>"` at the end of the loop body. In the first `td` you open a `strong` and close a `span`. Variables `$rowac`, `$rowdd`, etc are undefined. Can you show us your SQL?

Comment: i have updated my code @FelippeDuarte

Comment: We have to see the whole code. But i think in first place, it seem's that you need a view for that.

Comment: Sp how to de that

Answer (score 0):

**First,** check if your database is connected.

**Second**, check if PHP is working.

**Third,** your code problem:

**You forgot to add this line before while() loop**

```
echo '<table>';
```